# Separating the Complex Error Function into Real and Imaginary parts

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm trying to do a numerical integral of the following form:

$$\int_a^b (\mathbb{R}\left[\operatorname{erfi}(z)\right])^2 \, dz$$

That is, I would like to integrate the square of the real portion of the complex error function over some range (i.e. and neglect the contribution from the square of the complex component of $\operatorname{erfi}(z)$).. Does anybody know of a fast and precise way to implement this numerically? I'm working with the libcerf library in $C$, but it is unable to adequately express this result in a closed fashion with the error function.

Thank you.

Comment: For whomever is voting to close: I think this is probably the best place to ask this question as there aren't many programming sites that can handle questions like this one due to the rather math-heavy nature of the question.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I agree with you in part; but I'd like to point out the existence of http://scicomp.stackexchange.com where these kinds of problems may be better addressed. (I don't want to propose a migrate because scicomp is still in beta.)

Comment: This is a much more math focused question than what is typically posted to scicomp. I think it should stay.

Comment: Are your limits of integration $a$ and $b$ real or complex? The erfi function has a closed form integral. If you want to integrate along a line segment or a (deformable?) path in the complex plane then this gets more interesting.